# Fail to run laika framework for meteor

Tags: meteor, laika

I'm trying to run laika on my VM, but it still when I run the laika script, there is an error.

Here is the error :

```
nodejs [rebolon] /home/project/hello-laika % sudo laika

  injecting laika...
  loading phantomjs...
  loading initial app pool...

    /root/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/lib/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13
    throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe

    ^

  re-installing node-fibers...
  node-fibers reinstalled! run `laika` again!
  cleaning up injected code
```

I installed laika like this :

```
  sudo npm install -g laika
  sudo npm install -g phantomjs
  apt-get install libfontconfig1 // coz phantomjs crashed
  mongod --smallfiles --noprealloc --dbpath /mnt/tmpfs
```

Here is what I get when I check fibers package :

```
  nodejs [rebolon] /home/project/hello-laika % npm list fibers
  /home
  └─┬ laika@0.2.2
    └── fibers@1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed with laika version `0.2.4`. Try updating laika

If you still having problems try to make a [issue on the github repo](https://github.com/arunoda/laika/issues)

Comment: still fail, I'm trying to reinstall meteor and i will tell you if it's better

Comment: have you installed phantomjs on the system? it is available via $PATH?

Comment: yep it's available (i'm contacting you with mail and i will update the thread when a solution will be found)

Comment: great. I'll have a look on the VM and lets hope we can dig the issue :)

Comment: Can you please install laika version 0.2.4+ and try again