# Couldn't get laika to work on meteor

Tags: meteor, laika

I'm using meteor 0.6.4, node 0.10.12 and laika 0.2.8. I followed the instructions on the getting started page and I get this error:

```
injecting laika...
loading phantomjs...
cleaning up injected code

/Users/camilo/.nvm/v0.10.12/lib/node_modules/laika/lib/app.js:124
  if(err) throw err;
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
  at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

I switched to laika 0.2.4 based on this question [Fail to run laika framework for meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345643/fail-to-run-laika-framework-for-meteor) and get the same error.

**Edit**

I'm using phantomjs 1.9.1 installed with homebrew

**Edit 2**

I updated laika to 0.2.13 and tried with mrt (I was using meteor) but now the problem is different. With `laika -D` I get this:

```
[laika log] accepting the following extensions: (js)

  injecting laika...
  loading phantomjs...
[app touch log] 
[app touch log] Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
[app touch log] 
[app touch log] Done installing smart packages

[app touch log] Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[app touch log] [[[[[ ~/Documents/Pruebas/Meteor/test ]]]]]

[app touch log] => Meteor server running on: http://localhost:25969/
```

After a while, this error appear:

```
phantom stderr: 

phantom stderr: child_process.js:927
    throw errnoException(process._errno, 'spawn');
          ^
Error: spawn EAGAIN
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:927:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:715:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/camilo/.nvm/v0.10.12/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs:12:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)

phantom crash: code 8
```

I uninstalled phantomjs, put the phantomjs binary on the same project folder and tested again but get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts, apparently the problem was with phantomjs. Installing it with homebrew or putting the binary directly on the project doesn't work for me. After update laika to `0.2.14` and install phantomjs with `sudo npm install -g phantomjs` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a phantomjs basic issue. But a issue with nodejs version used by `laika`.

Please update `laika` to `0.2.13` and run `laika -D` which gives some verbose logs. lets talk about after that.

Normally, if your project runs with meteor (not mrt), laika uses binary located at following location.

```
~/.meteor/tools/latest/bin/node
```